# Android room: automatic query code without check integrity

Tags: android, android-room

This question is an integration of [Room - Using external SQLites as well as internal DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495308/room-using-external-sqlites-as-well-as-internal-db).
In my application I am using a downloaded DB, that means that, theoretically, I don't know if the tables schemes changes, It can have a table "User" with 3 column and the next downloaded is with 4 columns, the olds 3 with a new one, un managed by the android application.
I would like use Android rooms to avoid write tedious queries and write it on class with tedious reading code.
So I tried to write a data class, like:

```
@Entity
data class User(
    val id :Integer,
    val name :String,
    val surname :String )
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM User where id=:id")
    fun getUser(id :Integer) :User?
}
@Database(entities = [User::class],exportSchema = false,version=1)
abstract class DownloadedDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}

fun test(context :Context, downloadedFile:String, id:Integer) : User? {
    val db= Room.databaseBuilder(context, DownloadedDatabase::class.java, downloadedFile).build()
    return db.userDao().getUser(id)
}
```

the user table actually has 4 column, so when I try to use it thrown a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema` because it see that the db table has 4 column instead of 3, but I cannot add the new column to user class because in a next version I can have a 5th new column.

must I write it SQLiteOpenHelper ?

Comment: "I am using a downloaded DB, that means that, theoretically, I don't know if the tables schemes changes" -- only use Room with databases that *you* control. "must I write it SQLiteOpenHelper ?" -- SQLDelight may handle this case better, as it might hold up so long as the query is valid and works. In general, Room, SQLDelight, and similar frameworks are designed around the developer knowing the database schema at compile time, and in your case, that is not possible, apparently.

Comment: I know it enough to create valid query at develop time, my problem is that the db can evolve without the app, but you are right, maybe I must look for alternative libraries